# listBox. Как вывести нормальные значения?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, list

Привет всем. 
Есть **listbox**. Надо занести данные в **listbox**. Почему не то значение добавляется.

Создаю объект

```
class1 s1 = new class1("exampleText");
```

Потом добавляю экземпляр класса к **списку**.

```
List<class1> st = new List<class1>();
st.Add(s1);
```

После этого в listBox добавляется **application1.class1** вместо "exampleText".

```
listBox1.Items.Add(s1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно, вам нужно перегрузить метод `ToString` в классе `class1` и вернуть в нем нужное строковое значение. По умолчанию, будучи неперегруженным, этот метод возвращает строковое имя класса объекта.

[How to: Override the ToString Method (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: excellent!