# Аргументы объекта

Tags: c#, ооп

Каким образом я могу вывести на экран аргументы моих объектов в методе cout?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Instr box_1 = new Instr(15,13,"tree");
        Instr box_2 = new Instr(53,35,"metal");
        cout(box_1);
        cout(box_2);            
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void cout(object g)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: @FoggyFinder извините, не понимаю

Comment: @FoggyFinder нужно вывести 2 числа и строку, которые содержит объект

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [listBox. Как вывести нормальные значения?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/163773/listbox-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: @FoggyFinder Благодарствую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void cout(object g)
{
    //нужно привести параметр к нужному вам типу
    Instr box = g as Instr;
    //если получилось, то вывести нужные значения
    if (box != null)
    {
         Console.WriteLine($"{box.НужноеСвойство}");
    }

}
```

Или переопределить метод `ToString()` в вашем классе `Instr`
для этого в этом классе напишите `override` нажмите пробел - вам студия выведет список возможных для переопределения методов, выбирайте  `ToString()`. А дальше в нем пропишите что-то типа

```
return $"{this.НужноеСвойство1} - {this.НужноеСвойство2}, {this.НужноеСвойство3}";
```

после этого вы в своем методе `public static void cout(object g)` сможете вызвать `ToString()` и вывести значения всех нужных вам свойств.